# Tail of binomial Distribution (Confused)

Tags: probability-distributions

If $X$ is the number of successes in a Binomial Distribution

Then,
$P(X \leq K) = \dbinom{n}{k} (1-p)^{(n-k)}$

However, when I apply it to the case where 
$p=0.003$
$n=1000$
$k=1$

I get $P= 50.43$!!!

What am I missing??

Comment: You don’t have to look that hard for an example that shows that something’s wrong: your formula says that if you toss a fair coin twice, you’re certain to get at most one head! $\binom21\left(1-\frac12\right)^{2-1}=1$. You’re also certain to get at most one tail, so you’re certain to get one of each.

Comment: But my question is how can a probability be > 1?

Comment: It can’t: the fact that your calculation produces a result greater than one proves that your calculation is incorrect. Similarly, the fact that it ‘shows’ that tossing two fair coins **must** result in one head and one tail, something that is obviously false, shows that your calculation is incorrect.

Comment: It is not my calculations, it is taken from a textbook. That is why I was confused.

Answer (score 2):

It should be $P(X = k) = \dbinom{n}{k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ and hence $P(X \leq k) = \sum_{r=0}^k\dbinom{n}{r} p^r(1-p)^{n-r}$.

Comment: That is true, but if you simplify the later you get $P(X \leq K) = \sum_{r=0}^k \dbinom{n}{r}p^r(1-p)^{n-r} \leq \dbinom{n}{n-k}(1-p)^{(n-k)}=\binom{n}{k}(1-p)^{(n-k)}$

Comment: @user966168: So what? Even if it’s correct, which I’ve not checked, that’s an inequality, not an equality. In your example it says that $P(X\le 1)$ is no bigger than about $50$. Since we already know that it’s less than $1$, that information is both correct and rather useless.

Comment: @user966168 Your simplification only shows that $P(X\le k)$ **cannot exceed** ${n\choose k}(1-p)^{n-k}$. It does not show that $P(X \leq K)$ is **equal to** ${n\choose k}(1-p)^{n-k}$.

Comment: I was saying the same thing. Someone used it in a peer reviewed paper as an approximation and I though there could be an explanation. Anyways, thanks for the comments.